# After content stream recreation (using PDFbox) getting error in axesPDF (insert spaces)?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

when I am recreating a pdf after some changes , if I use the output pdf in axesPDF to fix spaces issue I am getting "ERROR". The only difference I observed my input pdf have Array of tokens but my recreated pdf has Dictionary of elements. As shown in below. Does that cause the problem? How can I recreate similar structure? (Left one is input pdf right one output pdf after editing)

[image]

[Input pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JBzNcxOfB7e9J_DjOOJb5Q_I7UnplHUy/view?usp=sharing)

[output pdf with changes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPjgMSfkKU1fj5KdBoPE5xkQAm55e9rJ/view?usp=sharing)

The code I am using to save the pdf is

```
PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
writer.writeTokens(tokens);
out.close();
document.getPage(pg_ind).setContents(newContents);
newPDF.addPage(document.getPage(pg_ind));
newPDF.save()
```

### Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Updating question along with error.

[Another Input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mp_8ZXD4S373NJH7piwl3-Nm6fIX1TEJ/view?usp=sharing)

The error is

[image]

The button I used.

[image]

I am wondering this time even the content stream is in COSDictionary format it's giving error. Something else causing this.

Comment: *"The only difference I observed my input pdf have Array of tokens but my recreated pdf has Dictionary of elements."* - the page contents may be either a single content stream or an array of an arbitrary number of content streams. If axesPDF had problems with either variant, it would be useless. Thus, the problem most likely is more subtle. I'll take a look later in office.

Comment: Why I mentioned this "The only difference I observed my input pdf have Array of tokens but my recreated pdf has Dictionary of elements." is after I saved the pdf in axesPDF is throwing error when insert spaces. But same pdf in adobe If I click  "Preflight>Fix  problems in pdf tagging structure" after its again recreating array of an arbitrary number of content streams then the problem is fixing.

Comment: I had a look at the two versions of the document. At first glance I cannot recognize anything that should cause axesPDF to "ERROR" out. You may want to contact them and ask them for a reason. It may be an error in their software, or it may be a detail in the PDF that didn't leap to the eye.

Comment: I updated question with new use case.

Comment: Well, that really looks like you should contact axesPDF and ask them. There are issues in your file but they already are in the source file, before your change with pdfbox.

Comment: Can you help me how can I find the problems in my pdf and fix. Can you help me here?